# Loading huge records of an excel file to Core Data (Offline Storage)

Tags: objective-c, excel, core-data, nsmutablearray

Is it possible to load around 100,000 records from an excel file directly to CoreData.
I need to create an offline application with a database of 100,000 members.

What I did earlier for around 1000 members is that I have concatenate the columns of the excel file to create a string(adding the data to NSMutable array)..then I have called the core data manager to insert the array to the core data. (I have created a standalone class for this purpose.

```
    NSMutableArray* array= [NSMutableArray new];

    //the below lines are generated after concatenation in excel file
    [array addObject:@{@"id":@"1",@"name":@"John",@"Last Name":@"Smith",... other data}];
    [array addObject:@{@"id":@"w",@"name":@"Lara",@"Last Name":@"Smith",... other data}];

//Add the array to database
```

The issue that I am currently facing is that when I have added all the 100,000 records to the method, it is crashing once I call the standalone class.

I am stuck now and I need an advise on what should I do? 
Is there any possible way to insert such huge numbers of records directly from an excel file to DB? or what is the best practice to load such a huge number of rows.

Comment: Have you tried looping and adding (for example) 1000 records at a time?  You presumably don't need to add them all in one shot.

Comment: Also please provide crash logs.

Comment: I am not able to read them directly from the excel file.
 so do I need to create 100 methods in each i insert 1000 records? or is there a way to read directly batches from the excel file?

Comment: Then what is the tool you are using to decode the excel file? The information you provided is so not enough for us to help

Comment: Hi, i managed to create 100 methods as i mentioned an now the code is working perfectly. However i faced a weird issue, that the build is taking 2 hours till now and still not completed!! I think I should be considering saving files instead of loading it in the code